# Count rows in Excel where any column contains specific text

Tags: excel

[image]

I have a table like this and need to count the number of rows (not number of cells) that contain specific text for a result like this.

```
ABC      3
DEF      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For O2016 you can use following array formula:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(--($A$1:$D$6=A10),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1)^0))>0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Thank you - works well even when extended out to a 5000+ cell matrix

Answer (score 1):

With **Excel 365**, use:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(SEQUENCE(6) & ":" & SEQUENCE(6)),"ABC")>0,1,0))
```

where ***6*** is the number of rows; and similar for *DEF*

[image]

Comment: Thanks but am using Office 2016 and I don't know how to translate this solution into my version